# How to implement change and new tools in a small dev team?

Tags: team, tools, change

I have been tasked with producing a plan for implementing a slight change to the work of our developers (there are eight of us working at this company). The change affects a small portion of our work, but introduces a new tool that the developers aren't familiar with, and a new "step".

*Very* schematically the change looks like this

Before change:

1. Write stuff
2. Do thing X

After change:

1. Write stuff
2. Use tool A
3. Use tool B to do thing X

What I have done so far is that I've written documentation for the use of tool A and tool B.

My question is what should you be keeping in mind when introducing new tools/changes in development to a small development team? How do you assure that the transmission to the new way of doing things is smooth? What type of educational resources should be available?

(The tools introduced are for version control of database schema [so it's only when we make changes the database schema that our development is affected], but I figured that was irrelevant to the topic)

Comment: 8 people are small? That is already pretty huge team of people.

Comment: @Euphoric: We're currently >10 people on a subproject...

Comment: 8 developers in total on the entire company. I should probably clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

I hate when someone introduces new tool in hope in fixing some problem without actually discussing this with the developers themselves. So before you start implementing such a tool or forcing developers to use it, make sure they are aware of problems the tool is trying to solve and even better, make them agree that the tool is best way to solve said problem.

There is nothing worse than management adding new tools into development process and developers having to follow it in such a way that kills half of their productivity and morale.

Comment: Management in this case is one of the developers (my boss). There is no non-developers meddling with how the developers work at our shop.

Comment: There is a consensus that change needs to done. Though there are no opinion one this solution/these tools in particular. The attitude is pretty much "as long as it works".

Comment: Is there anyway to test this out first before making the entire group use it at once?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure your colleagues will follow the new process, you should take care about several things:

1) Create an easy to use Quickstart-type guide (I assume your documentation will suffice). Images and short but meaningful text should point everyone in the right direction.

2) Present the new workflow to your colleagues.

3) Point them towards the benefits of the new workflow. If there are no benefits - you might have a problem and a lot of work coming towrads you.

4) Make sure no one is circumventing the workflow. The more benefit the new process has, the easier this will be.

Comment: On 1) That's exactly what I've tried to do (with screenshoots! :) ). I haven't written anything like this before, but I hope it's pedagogical enough.

On 2) Sounds good!

On 3) There is a consensus there will be benefits, but I'll make sure to clearly point them out.

On 4) I'm afraid of this one, mostly due to old habits.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the problem this tool is suppose to solve. Sounds obvious, but you may not have a consensus on what the true problems are with your existing way of handling database changes. Does it take too long? Are mistakes made? Is it nearly impossible to roll-back? Poor documentation?

The team must be convinced this will solve those problems without a disproportionate amount of time and effort.

Make sure you have management support and that there are ways to track and have contingencies for not using the system properly and regularly. You can't just get by on the notion that they'll use it because we "told" them to.

Once you start the adoption and training process, keep your documentation up to date. I don't think you have to do some exhaustive data collection and study to see if this is working. If most of your devs can answer "yes" to the question, "Do you think this tool made managing our database easier?" It was probably successful. Perception is reality.

Comment: Currently mistakes are made (simply that people develop for the wrong database version). The new way will take longer time, however; so that's the trade off.

I haven't thought of tracking if the new way is being used properly. That seams like a valuable point!